# Global inbox email notification gets sent for already-read messages

Tags: bug, status-completed, global-inbox, email

I have my global inbox email set to notify me of unread messages daily.

I just got an email notification message saying

> The following items were added to your Stack Exchange global inbox since you last checked it on 2011-11-22:

The problem is, the message it's informing me about was posted yesterday, I read it yesterday (the red "you've got mail" indicator went away), and I've been on Stack Exchange sites several times since I got the message.  Plus, it only lists one message, when there's another comment on the [very same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8221699/331137).

I've had this happen before, just a few days ago.  In both situation, I'd read the message and cleared out the "new messages" indicator hours before I got the email.

Comment: well, it's not just restricted to emails - the notifications get sent when I've already read. And then again, some of them don't get delivered at all.

Comment: +1, I've noticed this too. Assumed it's something to do with caching.

Comment: +1 I've been getting this myself as well.

Comment: Are you seeing this behavior anymore?  We've made several changes here, shouldn't be an issue any longer...if it is we need to track it down.

Comment: @NickCraver I think the last time I noticed this happening was March 14.

Comment: @NickCraver: The last time I saw it happening was the day of my comment (30-03-2012).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We fixed this, ummmm, quite a while ago.  Marking this complete!