# Eeeeek! Where's my comment notification?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments, notifications, global-inbox

I revisited [one of my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8350528/331508), and was surprised to see a comment left, many hours before.

The thing is, I never got an inbox notification!

[image: Missing inbox notice]

The comment does show up in my ***responses*** list...

[image: Notice is in responses]

Just not my inbox.

~~~~
Note that ["Didn't get notification for comment on my answer"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110904/148310) is related but it's marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), and the problem persists.

Comment: Related [Global inbox email notification gets sent for already-read messages](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113317/133693)

Comment: I'd dropped a comment about me not getting any notifications

Comment: The backend (and front end) of notifications has changed considerably since this was posted. Closing as no-repro.

Comment: @Oded, Fair enough. Can't say I've seen this problem in the last few months, but it's also insidiously hard to spot. It was merest coincidence that I caught it the first time. I see that [almost the opposite issue was reported 4 months ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224550), but that may just be a less-serious caching delay?

Comment: That issue is that deletion of a post doesn't delete related notifications...