# Comment notification shows up under responses, but not top bar inbox

Tags: bug, comments, notifications, global-inbox, responses

Looking under [my responses tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1711796/dukeling?tab=responses), I see:

[image]

Looking under my inbox on the top bar, I see:

[image]

(I believe only I, and perhaps mods, can see either of these screens - sorry about that)

Note the two I circled are different comments, neither showing up in the other display.

The one I encircled in my inbox is actually [a comment on a deleted post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250636/how-to-get-pi-value?noredirect=1#comment33792806_22250636) (since it's a deleted post, 10k+ users only unfortunately), which may explain why it doesn't show up in my responses tab (I don't really care about that, and frankly this behaviour makes sense).

My question is - why does [the other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22246481/issue-creating-my-own-linkedlist-class-in-java#comment33793953_22246481)'s notification show up in my responses tab, but not my inbox?

Is it perhaps related to the deleted comment?

Comment: The link to responses tab is only accessible for you (the account owner), not us.

Comment: Just saying, [your response tab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1711796/dukeling?tab=responses) redirects to 404 for us.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eeeeek! Where's my comment notification?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114631/eeeeek-wheres-my-comment-notification) (I assume) - sorry, only saw this now, though it might be useful to keep this around as a note that it's still showing up, and as another example of it. Or it might be a new issue, I don't know - that's pretty old.

Comment: I wouldn't close it as a dupe, as the top bar changed since then.